# Contact name returned as blank by Contacts API call when the contact has a "Connected Profile"

Tags: google-contacts-api

This question didn't get answered on google contacts official forum, I hope people in stackoverflow could give me some help.  I am using google contacts API 3.0 and the url:https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full. If the user has a "Connected profile"(Google+ account), the getName() method will returns blank value for that contact.
Is there any workaround?